# Excel 2010: Formula for Sum and Return Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a workbook with a Summary sheet and a Data Set sheet with a linked table containing 700k+ records of financial data on investments. (In my particular case, it is real estate properties; but this is the same scenario as tracking stocks and dividends.) The Summary Sheet contains one row per property (investment) and shows the amount (of money) originally injected (i.e., input or invested) per property, with the expectation that the monetary output (or return on investment) will at some point equal that original injection/investment amount. The Data Set shows daily production (i.e., monetary output) per property, with one row per property *per date* (i.e., has *many* rows for each property) and cannot be edited. It should be noted that the PropName column is unreliable (inaccurate/inconsistent), and so PropID should be used to correlate the two sheets.

I would like to have a formula in the "100% Recovery Date" column on the Summary sheet that will tell me the date that the total (cumulative) Output reaches or exceeds 100% of Input (i.e., the date that the investment has been recouped). I assumed that I would need a formula to do the following, though I may be wrong:

1. Sum all production (return on investment) data for each Property, from oldest to newest (data set is already sorted this way),

   UNTIL it reaches 100% of the Original Input/investment (shown in Total Input column on Summary sheet),
2. then return the date (located in a field in the Data Set sheet) when 100% recovery is met,
3. If 100% recovery is not met, return "TBD".

For example, the desired 100%RecoveryDate for property 0764 (“Prop 1”) would be 6/7/2013 (from the sixth data row of the Data Set sheet) because  1.667000055+ 5.000999928 +1.667000055 + 3.334000111 + 5.000999928 (from the first *six* rows of the Data Set sheet) = 16.670000077, which is greater than 13 (Total Input for property 0764).

Any and all constructive feedback is welcome and most appreciated!

#### Sample of Summary Sheet:

```
PropID   PropName   TotalInput   CurrentOutput  100%RecoveryDate  ProgressToRecovery
 0764     Prop 1          13         71,820                              189%
 0736     Prop 2      30,711        134,746                              439%
 1680     Prop 3      25,014         52,887                              211%
 4078     Prop 4      29,494         36,705                              124%
 5226     Prop 5      43,983         41,438                               94%
 6427     Prop 6      28,786         50,855                              177%
 6683     Prop 7      19,231         60,501                              315%
 6739     Prop 8      28,350         48,229                              170%
 9153     Prop 9      37,888         28,125                               74%
 8020     Prop 10     31,429         41,094                              131%
```

#### Sample of Data Set:

```
PropID   PropName     Date          Output
 0764     Prop 1    6/1/2013      1.667000055
 0764     Prop 1    6/3/2013      5.000999928
 0764     Prop 1    6/7/2013      1.667000055
 0764     Prop 1    6/10/2013     3.334000111
 0736     Prop 2    6/19/2013   361
 0764     Prop 1    6/19/2013     5.000999928
 0764     Prop 1    6/22/2013     6.668000221
 0764     Prop 1    7/12/2013     3.334000111
 1680     Prop 3    7/17/2013   389
 0764     Prop 1    7/23/2013    10.00200081
 0736     Prop 2    8/2/2013    236
 4078     Prop 4    8/22/2013   236
 0764     Prop 1    8/25/2013     6.668000221
 0764     Prop 1    8/30/2013     3.334000111
 0764     Prop 1    8/31/2013     5.000999928
 0764     Prop 1    9/11/2013     1.667000055
 6427     Prop 6    9/15/2013  1018
 1680     Prop 3    9/16/2013   389
 0764     Prop 1    9/20/2013     6.668000221
 0764     Prop 1    9/22/2013    10.00200081
 0764     Prop 1    9/23/2013    10.00200081
 5226     Prop 5    9/23/2013   125
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to imagine how your summary sheet and data sheet looks like.  It would be good to include some sample data and your expected results so that others can help.  (You can use the "code sample" formatting option to help you present your table)

Comment: Forgive my bumbling ignorance; I attempted to paste samples but could not get them to be formatted in any legible fashion. I have a sample spreadsheet that I can attach... if I could figure out how to attach a file here. :/

Comment: You can take a screenshot instead of uploading. Or, paste the data, select it, and press Ctrl + K

Comment: I edited your question; please check that I didn’t do any damage. (Note that tabs don’t work well in Stack Exchange.) But I still don’t understand it.

Comment: Please try to make your question coherent. For example, you talk about “the Original Input”, but I don’t see any such column heading in your data. And I don’t understand the relationship between the two sheets. If they’re listing different properties (1-10 on the Summary sheet, 26-38 on the Data Set sheet), what do they have to do with each other? If they show complementary data about the same properties, then show the same properties on both sheets in your example. And finally, please give an example of what you want Excel to do for you. (Or is that in there already? I just can’t tell.)

Comment: Scott I did my best to clarify the question and replaced the Data Set sample table with complementary data to the first (sorry about that). I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: can you alter Data Set Sheet? if so it may be possible to add a column with cumulative percentage for a given `PropName`.

Then in Summary sheet you'll have to search for each `PropName` which line is above 100% and get the date...

Comment: I am glad you asked that question, I will edit the original question to clarify...

Comment: Frack. I was trying to do it (and confident i could success), but with editing the dataset sheet...

Comment: Macro allowed? else with some tricky matrix-function it may be possible...

Comment: I think macros would be fine, but I would need to check. It is a perpetually-updating spreadsheet, so as long as the macro won't interfere with the automatic updates to the Data Set table, it shouldn't be a problem... Although I have not written any macros in a very long time and then only basic ones.

Comment: Maybe I’m just dumb, but it’s still not crystal clear to me. I edited the question, again, to reflect my best guess as to what you mean (and include an example result); so, again, check that I didn’t guess wrong. Based on my guess at what the question is, I can’t figure out how to do it the way you want (without using macros, which I’m not strong at). I ***have*** figured out a way to do it that involves creating a 700K-row dummy sheet, that shadows the Data Set sheet. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, Scott, that would be acceptable! The only error I can see in your edit is that it no longer applies the final requirement, which is that once the date is found, it needs to stop. Else it will return each day's date after 100% is achieved. Unless you provided for that and I missed it?

Comment: Regarding “stop once the date is found,” I thought that it was implicit (i.e., superfluous) because (a) there’s only one row in the Summary table per property (so where would it put all the extra dates?) and (b) step 2 says “return”. (Most computer geeks would interpret “return” to mean terminate processing. For example, you wouldn’t say “Return home from the store _and then_ stop shopping.”)

Comment: By the way, when you respond to a post or a comment (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by “@”, as in “@Scott”. That way he gets notified. You can abbreviate, e.g., “@Scot”, or use an entire name (without spaces), e.g., “@ KennethL”. The author of a post is automatically notified of comments to that post. See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [this help page](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy sheet. 
Link it to the Data Set sheet as follows:

- Click in cell `A1`, and either

  - type `='Data Set'!A1`, or
  - type `=`, click on the “Data Set” tab, and click in cell `A1` on that sheet

  and then type <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on the checkmark to the left of the Formula Bar.
- Click in the Name Box (to the left of the Formula Bar)
  and type a range that covers all the rows in the Data Set sheet,
  including (at a minimum) the “PropID”, “Date” and “Output” columns. 
  (These are columns `A`, `C`, and `D` in the example, and you say you have 700K+ rows,
  so you might type `A1:D999999`.)
- Type <kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
  For illustration:
  [image: illustration of Excel gymnastics]
- Click in the Formula Bar (which should say `='Data Set'!A1`) and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then,

- Enter `=IF(SUMIFS($D$2:$D2,$A$2:$A2,$A2)>VLOOKUP($A2, Summary!A:C, 3,FALSE), ROW(), "")` into cell `G2` and type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Enter `=MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$999998=$A2), ($G$2:$G$999998), 999999))` into cell `H2` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, thus making it an “array formula”.
- Drag these down to row 999999.

  > Unfortunately, I can’t figure out how to get the Name Box trick to work for the array formula;
  >   you may just need to manually drag it.
- Go to the Summary sheet.
- In cell `E2` (the first “100%RecoveryDate”), enter: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Dummy!A:H,8,FALSE)), "No Data!", IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Dummy!A:H,8,FALSE)=999999, "TBD", INDEX(Dummy!C:C,VLOOKUP(A2,Dummy!A:H,8,FALSE))))`.
- Format the cell as a date.
- Center it if you want.
- Then drag it down to the last row of data on the Summary sheet.

> **Note:** You will need to modify the above if your Data Set ever reaches 1000000
> (one million) rows. 
> I hope the places are obvious.

Comment: I think my workbook is simply too large. The samples I gave here are extremely condensed versions of what I'm working with. Every time I get to the second step in your instructions (where I am to enter the =IF(SUMIFS($D$2:$D2,$A$2:$A2,$A2)>VLOOKUP($A2, Summary!A:C, 3,FALSE), ROW(), "") formula), Excel crashes. I have tried it more than ten times, including times when no one else was on the server (6 a.m. on a Sunday = no fun), and it crashes at the same point every time. I very much appreciate your help, but I think I will have to convince them to do this in Access.